# Brightness adjustment crashes 13.04

Tags: 13.04, ati, dell, brightness

I'm using ubuntu 13.04 64 bit on a Dell Studio 1558 with a ATI/AMD 5400 series graphics card running the AMD 13.4 graphics drivers and sometimes when I try to adjust the screen brightness, the entire system crashes. Sometimes the screen goes nuts and displays an array of different coloured blocks.

Is anyone experiencing the same issue or know how to fix it?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: try installing the [Sputnik kernel](https://launchpad.net/~canonical-hwe-team/+archive/sputnik-kernel) (which is designed for the Sputnik project - a Dell XPS studio pre-installed with Ubuntu 12), it addresses similar issues that came up on the studio XPS series.

Comment: i have the same problem on my dell inspiron after updating to 13.04 from 12.10

Comment: "i have the same problem on my dell inspiron after updating to 13.04 from 12.10"²

Answer (score 0):

See this https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1007765?comments=all.
 Apparently this error is recurrent for Inspiron. The solution [#71](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1007765/comments/71) had worked well for me on 12.10, but not anymore on 13.04. :/